# Possibility to skip few controllers while invoking popViewController, and reaching root view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the Below Structure:

1. window-> root_view_Controller = NavigationController->InitWithRoot->UITabViewController.
2. UITabViewController has two Tabs
3. UIView of First Table View Controller has a register button.
4. Clicking 'button'

   click_On_Button_In_TabView -> Pushes First View Controller -> Click_On_Button_In_FirstView_Controller -> Pushes Second View Controller.

**Question:**

5- Now, I want to jump from Second View Controller to `TabViewController`. 
   In other words,

```
 'back' button on Second View controller should skip First View Controller and display
  the tab bar controller [ ie: Window Root View Controller ] .
```

**Is below right approach?**

One way I thought of implementing the delegate method which Second view controller
invokes on first view controller, and first view controller pops up immediately from
`viewDidAppear`, But I m not sure if it is the right approach?

Comment: Depends on the allocation of knowledge and responsibility, so you need to say more about your delegate protocol and relationship. You can just use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I found the solution.

1) I can not use the default 'back' button to navigate to root view controller.

Rather, Introduce a new Left Bar Button Item, and in ViewDidLoad, Just

use the below Line:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popToRootViewController:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your back button execute this method:

```
[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```